# Not able to send request to deployed spring boot application (on ec2 instance) from local react app

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, cors

## Background

I have made an application with backend in **Spring Boot** and front end in **React**. When I was using both locally, the application worked flawlessly.

## Problem

When I deployed my backend to AWS EC2 instance, the request from frontend started to give cors error.

[Cors Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl1BU.png)

Here's my Spring CORS config (that works when both applications are running locally)

## Security Config Class

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    /**
     * Method to create a bean of password encoder to later save passwords in database encoded
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration builder) throws Exception {
        return builder.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Constants.CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Constants.CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Constants.CORS_EXPOSED_HEADERS);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Constants.CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration(Constants.CORS_CONFIGURATION_PATTERN, corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
}
```

## Constants Class

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String RESIDENT_NID_FRONT_IMAGE_URL = "/images/residents/nid/";
    public static final String RESIDENT_NID_BACK_IMAGE_URL = "/images/residents/nid/";
    public static final String UPLOADED_FOLDER_GUEST_IMAGE = "/images/guests/profile/";

    public static final Integer STATUS_SUCCESS = HttpStatus.OK.value();
    public static final Integer STATUS_BAD_REQUEST = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value();
    public static final Integer STATUS_NOT_FOUND = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value();
    public static final Integer STATUS_SERVER_ERROR = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value();
    public static final Integer STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value();
    public static final String UPLOADED_FOLDER_GUEST_DOC_IMAGE = "/images/guests/doc/" ;
    public static final String RESIDENT_IMAGE_URL = "/images/residents/profile/";
    public static final String FRONT = "FRONT";
    public static final String BACK = "BACK";
    public static final String SECRET = "SecretKeyToGenJWTs";
    public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
    public static final String PRIVILEGES = "privileges";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    public static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";

    public static final List<String> CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = List.of("http://127.0.0.1:3000", "http://localhost:3000", "*");
    public static final List<String> CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS = Arrays.asList(
            "Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
            "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    public static final List<String> CORS_EXPOSED_HEADERS =Arrays.asList(
            "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    public static final List<String> CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS =Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "OPTIONS");
    public static final String CORS_CONFIGURATION_PATTERN = "/**";

    public static final String [] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/authentication/web/login",
            "/authentication/web/signup"
    };

    public static String generateOtp(){
        String numbers = "0123456789";

        Random rndm_method = new Random();

        char[] otp = new char[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            // Use of charAt() method : to get character value
            // Use of nextInt() as it is scanning the value as int
            otp[i] =
                    numbers.charAt(rndm_method.nextInt(numbers.length()));
        }

        return Arrays.toString(otp);
    }
}
```

## Ending Notes

- The request works fine when I send it using postman
- Please don't bully if this is a repeated question

Comment: Can you post the request and response headers for the OPTIONS request and your POST request? With the info that you have provided, it looks like the you are setting 
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` which is [not right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) when you are setting "`*`" in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` configuration. Can you test by removing `*` from `public static final List<String> CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = List.of("http://127.0.0.1:3000", "http://localhost:3000", "*");` and let us know the result?

Comment: It worked by removing the '*'. I don't know when I wrote it there. Basically you can't use the "*" with  corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);. Thanks for your help